# How to export WMI values to a file?

Tags: windows-7, wmi

There is a way to export all the content off WMI from cmd interface to a txt file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `/output` switch to log output.

```
wmic /output:wmiclog.txt <command>
```

Comment: Do you know a way to export all the <command> values?

Comment: you want record everything? try `/record:wmiclog.txt` @Diogo_Rocha

Comment: wmic /record:wmilog.txt ???? I tried unsucessfull

Comment: `wmic /record:wmilog.txt your commands`